# Connect to remote postgreSQL database thru another server

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

There is client infrastructure containing two servers - server1 (files), server2 (database - postgreSQL). We have direct access to the server1 (ftp/ssh). Server2 is not accessible directly, only from server1 and only for database connections (so no ftp/ssh access). Is there some solution, how to connect pgadmin from localhost to server2 in this configuration (by using that intermediate server1)? We are using this tool because it is desktop tool and has some advantages to phppgadmin (no memory limit, ...).

Classic ssh tunnel works only to server1, but I cannot connect it to server2 thru server1. Maybe some configuration, or script would be needed on server1?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear waht  "ssh tunnel works only to server1" means, but this should work:

```
ssh -L 5432:server2:5432 user@server1
```

It would forward the local port 5432 to `server2:5432` tunneled via server1.

You would then point `pgadmin` to `localhost:5432`.

If this doesn't work, please edit your question to contain more information. Error messages, log file entries, relevant configurations etc.